# Is there any situation in which I wouldn't use std::make_shared?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

From the research I have done, it sounds like [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is the preferred way of constructing a `std::shared_ptr`. Specifically because:

1. It performs only one memory allocation, compared with using `new`, which performs at least two.
2. If the ctor passed to make_shared throws, then it won't leak, as it will with new.

My question is, assuming that I want a shared_ptr, should I *always* use `make_shared`, or are there cases where `new` is preferred?

Comment: `shared_ptr<int>(new int)` won't leak memory if the `shared_ptr` constructor throws; which is what your second point seems to imply to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the counter and the object share the same allocation, they also share the same deallocation.

The counter has to persist until the last `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` go away.  If you have a large object (or many small objects) with long-lasting `weak_ptr`s, this can cause memory contention if you allocate the `shared_ptr`s via `make_shared`.

Second, if you have a 3rd party API that hands you a pointer or a resource handle, and possibly has its own dispose functionality, `make_shared` is neither appropriate nor possible to use in every case.  Creating your own `make_` functions can keep the messy details out of the way lets you deal with this problem, and deals with the exception corner case as well.

Finally, while shared pointers are awesome, they are also overly powerful.  Quite often I want a `unique_ptr` or even a `boost::scoped_ptr`, or an intrusive reference counting pointer, or the like to represent ownership.  `shared_ptr` should be used only when the situation actually involves *shared* ownership of the resource: using it willy nilly because it is "easy" tends to end up with the resource equivalent of spaghetti code.

Comment: Bonus points for the last paragraph. While that wasn't adressed directly in the question, it cannot be said often enough in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to deal with legacy code which returns a dynamically allocated object. In which case, you would need to use the `std::shared_ptr<T>` ctor with the pointer parameter. It's not preferable to using `std::make_shared` but it does allow you to use all the `std::shared_ptr<T>` goodness with legacy code.

I know that this is not strictly equivalent to using the `std::shared_ptr<T>` ctor with `new` directly but it is a valid use case of `std::shared_ptr<T>` where `make_shared` cannot be utilised.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit uncertain about the interpretation of your question. I am assuming that it is justified to use a `shared_ptr<T>`; I can only second [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232983/341970) on the reasons why you wouldn't want to use `shared_ptr` in the first place.

There is one situation where you cannot use `make_shared` or `allocate_shared` to construct the `shared_ptr` but you need to use the corresponding ctor: If you need to pass in a custom deleter, see (3) and (4) at [the ctors of `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems using make_shared on a class with a private constructor (from a static factory method). I don't think there's an easy solution to this.

Comment: I think there's a defect that's been raised about this; should you be able to make `make_shared` a friend function? The standard is unclear whether it'll work or not.

Comment: I made a workaround that lets you use `make_shared` with a "private" constructor: http://ideone.com/O93w6o

Answer (score 0):

> should I always used make_shared, or are there cases where new is
>   preferred

`make_shared` is not allowed when we are storing a naked pointer in `shared_ptr` allocated by someone else. and it can only call `public` constructors. However there are some reports in some compiler about accessing protected constructor using make_shared [like this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/346743).